# Compiling OpenSource Packet Capture softwares

Tags: java, c++, c, gcc, arm

I am trying to compile open source packet capture softwares called JPCAP (http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/Jpcap/doc/). I am trying to build this software on ARM processor. I get the following error when I execute the make. I am a java developer and I use this JPCAP in my Java application. Please help me understand this error.

```
Simplified Make Command:
    gcc -fPIC -I/home/skolli/native/java/include -I/home/skolli/native/java/include/linux -I/usr/include *.c -o libjpcap.so -lp
    cap

Error:

init.c:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Why aren't you following the [instructions](http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/Jpcap/doc/install.html)?  None of the platform options in the Makefile specify `-fPIC`, and the Linux one requires `-shared`.

Comment: This was already downloaded and available on the box.I just took it over. I changed it and now its working fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, genpfault is right, usually the steps is documented as "./configure" and followed by make, and "make install".

Otherwise, compilation to generate shared libraries is for example as follows:

gcc -fpic -c foo.c
gcc -fpic -c bar.c

And combine foo.o and bar.o into a shared library as in

gcc -shared -o libshared.so foo.o bar.o